# validate_format_of string with áêìõü in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding

I'm making a french verb conjugation Rails website where users may insert conjugations of verbs like:

```
     se abstenir
     m'appelle
     êtes
     achète
```

And I need to validate_format_of those verbs. The apostrophes are quite easy, but what about the êèã characters?

By now I have:

```
    word_format = /\A[\w]+[' ]?[\w]*\z/
    validates_format_of (...), :with => word_format
```

Which clearly doesn't work since \w doesn't match them. Also including áêĩ(...) to the regexp gives me a invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII) error.

I also need to upcase of downcase those strings, which ruby is ignoring, resulting in 'VOUS êTES' for example. The trivial answer seems to be doing it by hand, but I hope Ruby/Rails to surprise me again.

Its seems to be a hard problem, and I wasn't expecting since Ruby/Rails power.

Anybody could give me a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to install [UnicodeUtils](https://github.com/lang/unicode_utils) for the upcasing thing.

```
#encoding: utf-8
require "unicode_utils/upcase"
puts UnicodeUtils.upcase("êtes Niño")#=> ÊTES NIÑO
```

The regex could look like this:

```
word_format = /\A[[:word:]]+[' ]?[[:word:]]*\z/
```

`/[[:word:]]/` - A character in one of the following Unicode general categories Letter, Mark, Number, Connector_Punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

It [looks like instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292395/how-to-match-accented-characters-with-a-regex) of `\w` you need to use the POSIX bracket expression `[:alpha]`.

```
word_format = /\A[:alpha]+[' ]?[\w]*\z/
```

Comment: Wrong answer: 'á'.match(/[:alpha]/) answers => nil...thanks anyway, but not useful