# How to match accented characters with a regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex, unicode, non-ascii-characters

I need the solutions to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292395/how-to-match-accented-characters-with-a-regex), except for Python! I've tried installing the regex library for Python, [as apparently](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t739967-enabling-the-use-of-posix-character-classes-in-python.html) that enables the use of POSIX expressions in Python's regexes, but nevertheless I guess it does not include Unicode characters in the `[:alpha:]` class. E.g.:

```
>>> re.search(r'[[:alpha:] ]+','Please work blåbær and NOW stop 123').group(0)
'Please work bl'
```

When I want it to match `Please work blåbær and NOW stop`

**EDIT:** I am using Python 2.7

**EDIT 2:** I tried the following:

```
>>> re.search(re.compile('[\w ]+', re.UNICODE),'Please work blåbær and NOW stop 123').group(0)
'Please work bl\xc3'
```

Not quite what I wanted (I want to match the part after the first non-ASCII character too), but at least it matched on character more than before. What should I be doing here to get it to match the rest of what I want?

**EDIT 3:** I don't want to match any non-"word" characters; by "word" I mean a-z, A-Z, space, and any accented variations of word characters. I hope I got my idea across; in a phrase like

```
lets match força, but stop before that comma
```

I want to match only `lets match força`

**EDIT 4:** So I tried to use Python 3 just for this one script:

```
>>> re.search(re.compile('[\w ]+', re.UNICODE),'lets match força, but stop before that comma').group(0)
'lets match força'
```

I guess it works for the most part in Python 3, except that it also matches numbers (which I definitely don't want) and underscores. Any way to fix this, in Python 2 *or* 3?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to account for accent characters for regex in Python?](/q/18663644/90527)

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear which python version you are using. if you use 2.x then you maybe have an unicode issue. see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/393856/1107807) for further pointers and feel free to update your question to elaborate further.

Im quite surprissed, that i can't convert the accented character to proper unicode representation...

but there are workaround:

```
re.search(re.compile('((\w+\s)|(\w+\W+\w+\s))+', re.UNICODE), ur'Please work blåbær and NOW stop 123').group(0)
```

or

```
re.search(re.compile('\D+', re.UNICODE), ur'Please work blåbær and NOW stop 123').group(0)
```