# PHP preg_match: any letter but no numbers (and symbols)

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to set a validation rule for a field in my form that checks that the input only contains letters.

At first I tried to make a function that returned true if there were no numbers in the string, for that I used preg_match:

```
function my_format($str)
{
   return preg_match('/^([^0-9])$', $str);
}
```

It doesn't matter how many times I look at the php manual, it seems like I won't get to understand how to create the pattern I want. What's wrong with what I made?

But I'd like to extend the question: I want the input text to contain any letter but no numbers nor symbols, like question marks, exclamation marks, and all those you can imagine. BUT the letters I want are not only a-z, I want letters with all kinds of accents, as those used in Spanish, Portuguese, Swedish, Polish, Serbian, Islandic...

I guess this is no easy task and hard or impossible to do with preg_match. It there any library that covers my exact needs?

Comment: Input is utf-8 ? So you want to check, if the string only consists of white-spaces and any kind of letter from any kind of language, nothing else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using utf-8 encoded input, go for [unicode regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html). Using the `u modifier`.

This one would match a string that only consists of letters and any kind of whitespace/invisible separators:

```
preg_match('~^[\p{L}\p{Z}]+$~u', $str);
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all,Merry Christmas.

You are on the right track with the first one, just missing a + to match one or more non-number characters:

```
preg_match('/^([^0-9]+)$/', $str);
```

As you can see, 0-9 is a range, from number 0 to 9. This applies to some other cases, like a-z or A-Z, the '-' is special and it indicates that it is a range. for 0-9, you can use shorthand of \d like:

```
preg_match('/^([^\d]+)$/', $str);
```

For symbols, if your list is punctuations . , " ' ? ! ; : # $ % & ( ) * + - / < > = @ [ ] \ ^ _ { } | ~, there is a shorthand.

```
preg_match('/^([^[:punct:]]+)$/', $str);
```

Combined you get:

```
preg_match('/^([^[:punct:]\d]+)$/', $str);
```

Comment: For the first glance, you forgot the end delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

```
function my_format($str)
{
   return preg_match('/^\p{L}+$/', $str);
}
```

Simpler than you think about!

> \p{L} matches any kind of letter from any language

Answer (score 1):

Use the `[:alpha:]` POSIX expression.

```
function my_format($str) {
    return preg_match('/[[:alpha:]]+/u', $str);
}
```

The extra `[]` turns the POSIX into a range modified by the `+` to match 1 or more alphabetical characters. [As you can see, the `:alpha:` POSIX matches accented characters as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292395/how-to-match-accented-characters-with-a-regex)

If you want to include whitespace, just add `\s` to the range:

```
preg_match('/[[:alpha:]\s]+/u', $str);
```

EDIT: Sorry, I misread your question when I looked over it a second time and thought you wanted punctuation. I've taken it back out.

Comment: Thanks.  This was a good reminder to me to use [:alpha:] and not [a-zA-Z].

Comment: When you use `[[:alpha:]]` POSIX named class you should use `u` flag to match accented characters as well, which you didn't.

Comment: @revo Do you have a source for this? Does the `u` follow the `/` after the regex?

Comment: I'm so lazy to hunt it for you but you can test it somewhere online, and yes the flag will following `/` at the end.

Comment: [Providing my own source](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) for @revo's instructions. The `u` flag treats patterns strings as UTF-8

Comment: With that everything matches, I want to exclude numbers and symbols.